# How can I get this anchor link to look like a button

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

how can I get this to look like a button? I have tried the webkit but it doesn't seem to be working I must be doing something wrong. I have attached an image of what it looks like and what I am tying to get it to look like. Using HTML5 CSS3 and bootstrap. Your help is appreciated!

[image: This is an image of what it looks like; and below it what I want it to look like]

```
<div class="btn-one">
<a href="#h3" class="button">Scroll Down to Learn More</a>
</div>
```

down the page I put the anchor

It works properly but it just doesn't look the way it should.

CSS

```
a.button {
text-decoration: none;
color: #00bfff;
font-size: 18px;
text-transform: uppercase;
letter-spacing: .5px;
display: inline-block;
padding: 10px 30px;
margin: 20px;
font-weight: 400;
border-color: #00bfff;
border-width: 1px;
-webkit-border-radius: 50%;
-webkit-border-color:#00bfff;
-moz-border-radius: 50%;
-ms-border-radius: 50%;
-o-border-radius: 50%;
}

.btn-one {
padding: 2%;
font-weight: 400;
}
```

Comment: Can't see the attached image. If you are using Bootstrap a starting point might be to inspect the element and make sure Bootstrap styles are not overriding what you are defining.

Comment: I added it. My apologies

Comment: No worries - I've added an answer. For future reference, it might be useful to add a small CodePen of your code sample so anyone can easily jump in and see the problem. You're likely to get faster answers if you do that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the issue is the lack of defining a border-style to your element. If you use the shorthand version of defining the border (for simplicity), you'll see it appear. I've sampled some CSS below and altered the border-radius, as at 50% it looked like an oval and not your desired effect.

```
a.button {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #00bfff;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: .5px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    margin: 20px;
    font-weight: 400;
    border: 1px solid #00bfff;
    -webkit-border-radius: 40px;
    -moz-border-radius: 40px;
    -ms-border-radius: 40px;
    -o-border-radius: 40px;
}

.btn-one {
    padding: 2%;
    font-weight: 400;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to use

```
-webkit-border-radius: 40px;
-moz-border-radius: 40px;
-ms-border-radius: 40px;
-o-border-radius: 40px;
```

Just use:

```
 border:#00bfff 1px solid;
border-radius: 25px;
```

This is more optimized code

```css
a.button {
text-decoration: none;
color: #00bfff;
font-size: 18px;
text-transform: uppercase;
letter-spacing: .5px;
display: inline-block;
padding: 10px 30px;
margin: 20px;
font-weight: 400;
border:#00bfff 1px solid;
border-radius: 25px;

}

.btn-one {
padding: 2%;
font-weight: 400;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn-one">
<a href="#h3" class="button">Scroll Down to Learn More</a>
</div>
```